# Query to join left table with latest record on the right table using inner join

Tags: sql, oracle11g, inner-join

Below are the two tables of an oracle database(11g):

Table 1:  EXPORT_TABLE

```
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (INTBA,INDEXNAME,BANAME,SCBA,NAME,NVRCOUNTRY) values ('133520', 'Hong Kong',659923,'0',' Trustee Limited','HK');

Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (INTBA,INDEXNAME,BANAME,SCBA,NAME,NVRCOUNTRY) values ('133516',' Holdings ',659923,'0',' Banking Holdings','CH');
```

Table 2 : ba_name

```
Insert into ba_name (MAINKEY,INTBA,CLIENTNAME,BASEQ,TRAN_DATE,name_type_code,indx_name_e_dte) values (1000,'133520','ROYAL Challenge', 0, '2016-MAR-10' ,'001',NULL);

Insert into ba_name (MAINKEY,INTBA,CLIENTNAME,BASEQ,TRAN_DATE,name_type_code,indx_name_e_dte) values (1001,'133520','Royal Challenge',0, '2016-SEPT-24','001',NULL);

Insert into ba_name (MAINKEY,INTBA,CLIENTNAME,BASEQ,TRAN_DATE,name_type_code,indx_name_e_dte) values (1003, '133516','Deloitte AG','0','2016-MAY-20','001',NULL);
```

The requirement requires to join EXPORT_TABLE with  ba_name on a join condition mentioned below

```
          ba_name.INTBA = EXPORT_TABLE.INTBA
          AND ba_name.name_type_code = '0001'
          AND ba_name.indx_name_e_dte IS NULL
```

In the second table 'ba_name' , INTBA is not a unique key and the second table 'ba_name ' can have multiple rows of same INTBA which can occur on different transaction dates. Its a legacy system(cantdo anything now)

Since we have duplicate entries with INTBA, we need to join  EXPORT_TABLE (column name=INTBA)  with that of  ba_name table , which is  having the latest TRAN_DATE.

In other words i would like to join the  EXPORT_TABLE  with the matching record on  ba_name  which is very recent or having latest TRAN_DATE date.  I wnat to join INTBA '133520' OF EXPORT_TABLE with INTBA '133520' of ba_name  having tran_date as '2016-SEPT-24' , not the one having MARCH as tran_date ('2016-MAR-10').

```
THE RESULT SET WANTED TO SEE IS :


                             (intBA |CLIENTNAME| BASEQ | TRAN_DATE)
                             ======================================

                             133520 |'Royal Challenge'| 0  | '2016-SEPT-24'
                             133516 |'Deloitte AG'    |'0' | '2016-MAY-20'
```

However  tried with  below query :

```
SELECT   EXPORT_TABLE.intBA, 
         ba_name.CLIENTNAME,
         ba_name.BASEQ,             
         ba_name.TRAN_DATE

         FROM EXPORT_TABLE   INNER JOIN  ba_name

       ON ba_name.INTBA = EXPORT_TABLE.INTBA

              AND ba_name.name_type_code = '0001'
              AND ba_name.indx_name_e_dte IS NULL

I got below result which is incorrect:


                             (intBA |CLIENTNAME| BASEQ | TRAN_DATE)
                             ======================================

                             133520 |'Royal Challenge'| 0  | '2016-SEPT-24'
                             133520 |'RoYAL Challenge'| 0  | '2016-MAR-10'
                             133516 |'Deloitte AG'    | 0 | '2016-MAY-20'
```

Can you suggest how can I join left side table with the matching row of second(right) table having the latest transaction date.

Comment: Remove the RDMBS tags that you don't need. Oracle <> MySQL <> SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One common method is `row_number()`:

```
SELECT e.intBA, n.CLIENTNAME, n.BASEQ, n.TRAN_DATE
FROM EXPORT_TABLE e INNER JOIN
     (SELECT n.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY n.INTBA ORDER BY n.TRAN_DATE DESC) as seqnum
      FROM ba_name n
      WHERE n.name_type_code = '0001' AND n.indx_name_e_dte IS NULL
     ) n
     ON n.INTBA = e.INTBA AND n.seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: I do agree  the query gives me correct result . The  'e' table has around 36k records and 'n' table  has 173k records. Do you think above is the best solution to have considering the number of records involved in join and the query execution times....

Comment: @maheshkumarbm . . . Of course, the best solution depends on the data distributions, hardware, and indexes and other optimizations.  This is a very reasonable solution under most circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

ou might be looking for something like:
the added subselect returns the latest TRAN_DATE for each combination

```
    SELECT EXP.intBA, 
           bae.CLIENTNAME,
           ba.BASEQ,             
           ba.TRAN_DATE
      FROM EXPORT_TABLE EXP 
INNER JOIN ba_name ba
        ON ba.INTBA          = EXP.INTBA
       AND ba.name_type_code = '0001'
       AND ba.indx_name_e_dte IS NULL
       AND ba.TRAN_DATE = (SELECT MAX(TRAN_DATE) FROM ba_name bamax
                            WHERE bamax.INTBA = ba.INTBA
                              AND bamax.name_type_code = '0001'
                              AND bamax.indx_name_e_dte IS NULL
                          )
```

Comment: I agree that it will give me correct result, however whenever im dealing with tables having lakhs of records ( here i do have around 1,73,000 records on second table) , would it be wiser to  join with inner sub clause for each record on left side???

Comment: have a look at the execution plan, how the query works at your environment. there shouldn't be any problem